# What is the meaning of ほうで here?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 寺尾さんは「１つでもアレルギーのある食品があるとお弁当を持たせています。週に１回、給食が食べられたらいい**ほうで**、他の子どもたちと一緒に食事ができない娘を見るのは親としてはとてもつらいです」と話していました。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_1004.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_003))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two sentences of …食べられたらいいほうだ and …つらいです combined together, with だ conjugated into the conjunctive form で.

ほう is a noun that's used as a grammatical component for comparison. In concrete, 週に一度給食が食べられたらいいほうだ means "if you can have school lunch once a week, that's better (than average)".